# Android Studio could not view system packages in explorer

Tags: android, android-studio

This may be a stupid question, but I just can't figure it out. I've just started using Android Studio 2.1.2.

I would like to explore through Package explorer and view some of the default classes, say for example DialtactsActivity. I am not sure how to explore this. So I need to understand how to navigate to the package explorer. The second will the default packages will be shown in the package explorer or should i explicitly open from a location.

[image]

Comment: Can you add image of what you get in Android Studio currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see External libraries -> here is libraries with default classes and resources.

Comment: I hope you got that default classes.

Comment: Do you mean Libraries icon in the explorer window in the above picture?

Comment: Yes. Which library you have used?

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for com.android.contacts.activities package. I am not able to find it from here. Is there any way i can search for it

Comment: You got that class?

Comment: No. I am not able to view the class. I am searching for the class DialtactsActivity. I am expecting the Package explorer windows as shown in the pic above as given to me in the Tutorial. Neither am getting the Package Explorer as given above or am able to explore the class in the Libraries window that is displayed in my Android studio